# Post Request return status code 500 Angular request to spring boot backend

Tags: java, angular, spring, post, rest

getting 500 status code error when using the following request

```
createPost(postPayload: CreatePostPayload): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/posts/', postPayload);
  }
```

request works fine on postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally was able to solve this.
It was the fact that the authentication token was not included in the header of the post request, that's why it works fine on postman. Thanks to Murugan and Ahmed who hinted to check the headers I managed to solve it like this

```
  createPost(postPayload: CreatePostPayload): Observable<any> {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", this.localStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken'));

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/posts/', postPayload, {    
        observe: 'response',    
        headers: headers           
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it using HttpClient. Check you post() body and headers

Answer (score 0):

```
 createPost(postPayload: CreatePostPayload): Observable<any> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/posts', postPayload, {    
            observe: 'response',    
            headers: headers           
        });
      }
```

Comment: when I tried your code the error switched from 500 to 404

Comment: I think the I found the real problem in the back-end but I don't know how to fix it, it looks like for some reason there is an error retrieving the current user to assign the post to.
```java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User```